# React Native - Javascript / native interaction question

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app in React Native for Android and iOS and one of the things it does is perform an authentication flow with a server. The authentication has several http communication steps with encryption etc.)
As the authentication is 95% the same for iOS and Android I was thinking there could be a common authentication manager type class written in Javascript.

However I was wondering is the best way of implementing these features:

1. The authentication would be performed by the JS class, but when that starts is different for Android and iOS, therefore the native code should tell the JS authentication code to start.
   What is the best way of the native code informing the JS class to start? An event?
2. The native code needs to check what the status of the authentication is (unauthorized, authorized, auth in progress, auth failed etc.). What is the best way of this state information being shared by the JS code/queried by the native code?

Answer (score 0):

RN has RCT(react) async Bridge that communicates between These two different worlds (IOS, Android), You have to implement your native logic separately inside the on relevant platform and can use in JS

[Native Module link to docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)

[Android Native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

[IOS Native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios)